# How to prove that det($A^{T}A$) is nonnegative?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Why is the determinant of the product of a matrix and its transpose nonnegative?

Comment: What properties of the determinant do you know?

Comment: Is $A$ real? Is it square?

Comment: Bella: You need to clarify if $A$ is a square $n\times n$ matrix, for some $n$

Comment: As you can see, I removed that portion of my comment. We still need Bella to respond and clarify. Thanks! You're correct, another approach may be needed. But I'm just sensing from the level of question that the question concerns square matrices with real entries.

Comment: Given the answer of Alex Jordan, there is no more need now.

Comment: @awllower: And I upvoted Alex.Jordan's answer! ;-)

Comment: That is worth it indeed.

Answer (score 9):

I assume that $A$ is real.

$A^TA$ is symmetric, so it is (orthogonally) diagonalizable. So its determinant is the product of its eigenvalues. Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue for $\vec{v}$, where $\vec{v}$ is an eigenvector of $A^TA$.

Using inner product notation:
$$0\le\langle A\vec{v},A\vec{v}\rangle=(A\vec{v})^T(A\vec{v})=\vec{v}^TA^TA\vec{v}=\vec{v}^T\lambda\vec{v}=\lambda\langle\vec{v},\vec{v}\rangle$$

This implies that $\lambda$ is nonnegative, since $\langle\vec{v},\vec{v}\rangle>0$. So the determinant is a product of nonnegative real numbers, and therefore a nonnegative real number. Note that this shows something much more specific about $A^TA$ than merely having positive determinant.

(If you prefer dot product notation:
$$0\le( A\vec{v})\cdot(A\vec{v})=(A\vec{v})^T(A\vec{v})=\vec{v}^TA^TA\vec{v}=\vec{v}^T\lambda\vec{v}=\lambda\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}$$)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming $A$ is square, (hence $\det (A)$ is defined):

Recall $$\det(A) = \det(A^T)$$
$$\det(A^TA) = \det(A^T)\det(A)$$

What does this imply about $\det(A^TA)$ if

- If $\det A > 0?$
- If $\det A < 0$?
- If $\det A = 0$?

Comment: What if A is not square?

Comment: It's not clear from OP's question that A is square; $\det(A)$ might not be defined.

Comment: $A^TA$ is always square regardless of what $A$ is, and always can have its determinant taken.

Comment: You're all correct. I tried to state my assumptions clearly, with no clarification from the OP. I think this is a good question for two levels at which the OP may be asking it: first encounter with determinants of square matrices/properties of determinants, or at a place where learning about eigenvalues...

Answer (score 0):

Consider $A=Q\cdot R$ where $R$ is a square matrix and the columns of $Q$  consist of an orthonormal basis of the column space of $A$. Now $\det(A^T A)=\det((QR)^T(QR))=\det(R^TQ^TQR)=\det(R^T)\det(Q^TQ)\det(R)$, and since $Q^TQ$ is a unit matrix and its determinant is 1, the final product is $\det(R^T)\det(R)=\det(R)\det(R)=\det(R)^2$, which is non-negative (see also amWhy's argument above).