# Proving a determinant equation

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I was trying to solve this equation, when i came up with an idea, but couldn't prove it.

The task is: Let the matrices A and B be with the same dimensions. So if A is (2x3) matrice then B is (2x3) matrice. (Is bounds/dimension the right word ? )
Prove that,

$| (A^T * B) | )^2 \le |A^T * A| |B^T * B|$

Anyway i have to prove this , but i thought that determinants can be negative, but i can't find any negative determinants , atleast which look like $|B^T * B|$ . Other thought that if i can show that right side is negative, the equation wouldn't hold , because the right side is always not negative.

My question is : Is there such B, that the Determinant of B transposed multiplied by B is negative ? 
If not , then why can't it be negative  ?

Comment: The question can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321050/how-to-prove-that-detata-is-nonnegative)

Comment: What i posted before was only for square matrices - a proof for the general case can be found above. (to answer your question, then det$(B^tB)$ is simply $det(B)^2$, which can't be negative)

Comment: So even if it is not square matrice, what you said is true ? That proof is too hard for me to understand tho ... It's my 2nd algebra lesson ... haven't gotten to vectors yet.

Comment: The problem is that the determinant for non-square matrices doesnt exist, it only exists for $B^tB$ because it is square - the link provided is a more general proof for all matrices B

Comment: This is an application of the Binet-Cauchy theorem. In a certain sense, $\det(A^TB)$ is an euclidean scalar product, of outer vector products of the columns of $A$ and $B$ with the coordinate formula $$\det(A^TB)=\sum_{I=(i_1<i_2<...<i_m)}\det(A_I)\,\det(B_I),$$ where $A_I$ is the square matrix with the rows of $A$ indexed by $I$. That is why the formula in the question looks like the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, since it is a special case of it. But that is not for the second algebra lesson.

Comment: I do not understand your indexing , what do you mean by $I=(i_1<i_2<...<i_m)$
Yeah i get the feeling that i have to study ahead to solve this... It gives bonus points

Comment: $I=(i_1,i_2,...,i_m)\in\Bbb N^m$ is a multi-index. In the sum only those are considered that are sorted tuples in the $1,...,n$ range, $1\le i_1<i_2<...<i_m\le n$. So that the matrix $A_I$ can be defined to be that quadratic submatrix of $A$ that is composed of rows number $i_1,i_2,...,i_m$.

Comment: @La'tel: Obviously, you are not studying this inequality in the context of outer vector products and Graßmannians. Can you outline the context that this problem was posed in, theorems, methods of your course that are related to determinants and Gramian matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be non-trivial, the format of the matrices must be "tall", more rows than columns, $m\ge n$. (If not, $\det(A^TA)=\det(A^TB)=\det(B^TB)=0$ because of non-maximal rank of the products.)

Now use QR decompositions $A=UR$ and $B=VS$ in the "small" variant where $U$ and $V$ have the same format as $A$ and $B$ with orthonormal columns. $R$ and $S$ are upper triangular $n\times n$ matrices. Then
\begin{align}
\det(A^TA)&=\det(R^TR)=\det(R)^2\\
\det(B^TB)&=\det(S^TS)=\det(S)^2\\
\det(A^TB)&=\det(R^T(U^TV)S)=\det(R)\det(S)\det(U^TV)
\end{align}
so the problem reduces to the special case $|\det(U^TV)|\le 1$. Here one can perhaps use the spat volume property of the determinant, and its maximum for given side lengths,
$$
|\det(\vec x_1,\vec x_2,...,\vec x_n)|\le \|\vec x_1\|\,\|\vec x_2\|\,...\,\|\vec x_n\|
$$
that is, applied to the current situation,
$$
|\det(U^TV)|\le \|U^Tv_1\|\,\|U^Tv_2\|\,...\,\|U^Tv_n\|.
$$